# Android Studio Application Crashes on Start

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api

I am trying to make a tasker plugin, and all seems to be good until I try to configure the plugin. Here is the different code:

edit_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        >

    </Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the edit_activity.java

```
/**
* This is the "Edit" activity for a Locale Plug-in.
* <p/>
* This Activity can be started in one of two states:
* <ul>
* <li>New plug-in instance: The Activity's Intent will not contain
* {@link com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent#EXTRA_BUNDLE}.</li>
* <li>Old plug-in instance: The Activity's Intent will contain
* {@link com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent#EXTRA_BUNDLE} from a previously saved plug-in instance that the
* user is editing.</li>
* </ul>
*
* @see com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent#ACTION_EDIT_SETTING
* @see com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent#EXTRA_BUNDLE
*/

public final class EditActivity extends AbstractPluginActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

Spinner spinner1;

public void setSound (String Mode){
    if (Mode == "Normal") {AudioManager audiomanage = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audiomanage.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);}
    else if (Mode == "Vibrate") {AudioManager audiomanage = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audiomanage.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);}
    else {AudioManager audiomanage = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audiomanage.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);}
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    spinner1= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Modes,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    BundleScrubber.scrub(getIntent());

    final Bundle localeBundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra(com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent.EXTRA_BUNDLE);
    BundleScrubber.scrub(localeBundle);

    setContentView(R.layout.edit_activity);

    if (null == savedInstanceState) {
        if (PluginBundleManager.isBundleValid(localeBundle)) {
            final String message =
                    localeBundle.getString(PluginBundleManager.BUNDLE_EXTRA_STRING_MESSAGE);
            ((EditText) findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(message);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    //User cancelled
    if (isCanceled()) {
        super.finish();
        return;
    }

    //Sanity check
    final String message = ((Spinner) findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).getSelectedItem().toString();
    if (message.length() <= 0) {
        super.finish();
        return;
    }

    final Intent resultIntent = new Intent();

    /*
     * This extra is the data to ourselves: either for the Activity or the BroadcastReceiver. Note
     * that anything placed in this Bundle must be available to Locale's class loader. So storing
     * String, int, and other standard objects will work just fine. Parcelable objects are not
     * acceptable, unless they also implement Serializable. Serializable objects must be standard
     * Android platform objects (A Serializable class private to this plug-in's APK cannot be
     * stored in the Bundle, as Locale's classloader will not recognize it).
     */
    final Bundle resultBundle = PluginBundleManager.generateBundle(getApplicationContext(), message);
    resultIntent.putExtra(com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent.EXTRA_BUNDLE, resultBundle);

    /*
     * The blurb is concise status text to be displayed in the host's UI (Tasker UI itself).
     */
    final String blurb = generateBlurb(getApplicationContext(), message);
    resultIntent.putExtra(com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent.EXTRA_STRING_BLURB, blurb);

    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    super.finish();
}

/**
 * @param context Application context.
 * @param message The toast message to be displayed by the plug-in. Cannot be null.
 * @return A blurb for the plug-in.
 */
/* package */
static String generateBlurb(final Context context, final String message) {
    final int maxBlurbLength = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.twofortyfouram_locale_maximum_blurb_length);

    String finalMessage = message;
    if (finalMessage.length() > maxBlurbLength)
        finalMessage = finalMessage.substring(0, maxBlurbLength);

    return finalMessage;
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView myText = (TextView) view;
    Toast.makeText(this,"You Selected "+myText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

}

Here is the FireReceiver.java

```
public final class FireReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

/**
 * @param context {@inheritDoc}.
 * @param intent the incoming {@link com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent#ACTION_FIRE_SETTING} Intent. This
 *            should contain the {@link com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent#EXTRA_BUNDLE} that was saved by
 *            {@link EditActivity} and later broadcast by Locale.
 */
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)
{
    /*
     * Always be strict on input parameters! A malicious third-party app could send a malformed Intent.
     */
    if (!com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent.ACTION_FIRE_SETTING.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            if (Constants.IS_LOGGABLE)
                Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, String.format(Locale.US, "Received unexpected Intent action %s", intent.getAction())); //$NON-NLS-1$
            return;
        }

        BundleScrubber.scrub(intent);

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra(com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent.EXTRA_BUNDLE);
        BundleScrubber.scrub(bundle);

        if (PluginBundleManager.isBundleValid(bundle))
        {
            final String message = bundle.getString(PluginBundleManager.BUNDLE_EXTRA_STRING_MESSAGE);
            EditActivity eta= new EditActivity();
            eta.setSound(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat of the error:

```
Process: com.yourcompany.yoursetting, PID: 11660
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yourcompany.yoursetting/com.yourcompany.yoursetting.ui.EditActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
at com.yourcompany.yoursetting.ui.EditActivity.onCreate(EditActivity.java:66)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182)         
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)      
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194
```

Comment: sometimes (always) the most important part is the logcat to see were it fails

Comment: Post your logcat and check your post. Part of your code is not well wrapped to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `setContentView()`  before you can call `findViewById()`. 
Otherwise, like in your code, the `findViewById()` returned always `null`. 
Normally you call `setContentView()` directly after the `super.onCreate()`.

For `logcat` understanding. This is your important part:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
at com.yourcompany.yoursetting.ui.EditActivity.onCreate(EditActivity.java:66)
```

This mean that you have an `Object` which is `null` (NullPointerException). The next line says that you call `setAdapter()` on a `null` `Object` which is located at your `EditActivity` in the `onCreate()` method on line 66.